# When using bootstrap with laravel jquery not being found

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Bootstrap CDN I have put both these links in a default template which I include in every page.

```
<script type=text/javascript src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The bootstrap is showing in the files but when I try to click on a button for example I get this error in the Developer Tools, 'Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery'.

I am also not using the Laravel form builder

Comment: Did you try to also link jquery from here https://code.jquery.com before linking bootstrap?

Comment: @GinoPane just tried this now but still nothing, thanks though

Comment: have you added `jquery.js` file before your bootstrap js file?

Comment: @Joey93 can you post code with linked jquery?

Comment: @GinoPane  sorry my mistake it was that I did not include jquery.js before the bootstrap jquery. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste this code to make it work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```